# Home Wifi Speed Fluctuations

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, mac

we're using the "Actiontec T3200" modem gateway provided by our ISP (TDS Telecom in mid-Tennessee).

we've been having bad speed fluctuations that's stumped us.
today we experimented by having 3 different Macbook Pro's (2017, 2018, & 2019 models) side-by-side, also with 2 different iPads & 3 iPhones to test with.

on all of them we used the SpeedTest.net service (on the computers, used Safari AND Chrome; & on the iDevices, used their app).

we made sure all were connecting to the same server.

and we did NOT run more than one at a time.

consistently, on 2 Mac's we got between 300-400 Mbps. the 3rd Mac couldn't get over 15-30 Mbps!!! (yes, that's Mbps, not MBps ;-)
likewise, on all the iDevices.
it was always consistent, the same devices kept getting the same dramatic results.

so yes, i thought maybe something was wrong with the ones getting the super low speeds, so i did a clean install on one, and i made a new user account on another. didn't make a bit of difference.

also restarted all devices at various times. didn't make any difference either.

i am no expert in networking. so tho i knew to look at the noise & channel etc stuff you can see by holding down the Option key & clicking the Airport icon in the menubar of the Mac's, i don't know what those numbers represent.

i even got admin access to the modem settings & hunted around, but didn't see anything that stood out to me as being a problem; it's all default settings from TDS.

so, yes we are having a TDS tek come out to the house next week to do whatever testing they can do and bring a different modem/gateway in case that's the issue, but i would still like to understand how this kind of huge difference in speeds on these devices can happen like this.

thanks for your thoughts & knowledge offerings.

Comment: I have had that brand replaced here (Hitron now). Ask for a new Modem and ask for the modem to be in Bridged mode and supply your own router.

Comment: When you option-click on the AirPort Menu Extra, look at the channel number. I'll bet that the devices that turned in good results had joined the 5GHz 802.11ac network (channel 36 and above are 5GHz), and the devices that turned in poor results had joined the 2.4GHz 802.11n network (channels 1-11 are 2.4GHz). On your Actiontec T3200's admin UI, see if you can make your 5GHz network have a different name (SSID) than your 2.4GHz network, so you can control which band your clients join.

Comment: Also put one computer on Ethernet to the modem (router) and see it it is stable

Comment: @John, thanks but, we'd rather just use the one device for simplicity; besides, it's working great on all the other devices i mentioned.

Comment: @Spiff, thanks, good idea. i checked & all devices are using the higher channels on 5GHz.

Comment: FYI: we're gonna experiment with the "wifispoof.com" app to change the MAC ID for the computer when the speed gets horribly slow. we tried it today & it "seemed" to work; the app has a 2 week trial period before buy. i'll report back if it works consistently or not. i've also read to try a VPN; will try that next if this app doesn't work. the reason for these 2 options is that we've read TDS will throttle the speed if it detects a lot of usage. thx.